# Do a Calculation using table calculation in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculation

I have 2 calculated fields A & B they both are calculated using Table calculation.

Now I want is to make bins using them like: 
Example: [My Table calculation A & B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3doA.png)

What I want to do is:-

IF A > 0 & B > 0 Then Case 1

IF A < 0 & B < 0 Then Case 2

IF A > 0 & B < 0 Then Case 3

IF A < 0 & B > 0 Then Case 4

Thank you for your response & apologize for not attaching the Workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly simple using IF + ELSEIFs - try the formula below:

```
IF (A > 0 & B > 0) THEN "Case 1"
ELSEIF (A < 0 & B < 0) THEN "Case 2"
ELSEIF (A > 0 & B < 0) THEN "Case 3"
ELSEIF (A < 0 & B > 0) THEN "Case 4"
END
```

This should return 4 distinct values *Case 1*, *Case 2*, *Case 3*, *Case 4* based on the input variables **A** and **B**. Hope this helps!